Origin of a Relation in the Proof of Theorem 10.6.4 in Beardon's Book
I'm studying the proof of the following theorem in Beardon's book.

Theorem 10.6.4: A group $ G $ is a $(p, q, r)$-Triangle group if and only if it is a discrete group of the first kind with signature $ (0; p, q, r) $.

In one part of the proof (3rd paragraph on P.280), the following relation comes out without suitable reference.

Suppose that $ G $ is a discrete group of conformal isometries with signature $ (0; p, q, r) $.
Let $ D $ be a convex fundamental polygon for $ G $ with, say, cycles of lengths $ N_p, N_q $ and $ N_r $ corresponding to the conjugacy classes associated with $ p $, $ q $, and $ r $.
Suppose also that there are $ t $ accidental cycles of lengths, say, $ M_1, \ldots, M_t $, so $ M_1 \geq 3 $.
Then we have the following;
$$
\text{h-area}(D) = [N_p + N_q + N_r + M_1 + \ldots + M_j]\pi - 2\pi - 2\pi t - 2\pi \left( \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} + \frac{1}{r} \right)
$$

I'm curious about the origin of this result in the book or any other source.
Could someone please provide a reference? -> Could someone please provide a reference and explain the formula above?
Reference
Beardon, Alan F. The geometry of discrete groups. Vol. 91. Springer Science & Business Media, 2012.

It is the Gauss-Bonnet theorem or Gauss-Bonnet formula.
OP is asking for references :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Gauss-BonnetFormula.html
https://archive.lib.msu.edu/crcmath/math/math/g/g040.htm
https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/mathematics/gauss-bonnet-theorem
https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Gauss-Bonnet_theorem
Here is the "best" reference I could find for mapping the terms & getting the over-all Expression :
https://ir.library.oregonstate.edu/downloads/ws859p982
Page 9 : Theorem 8 (Gauss-Bonnet) :
Let $∆$ be a hyperbolic triangle with angles $α,β,γ$.
Then the area of the triangle is $µ(∆) = π − α − β − γ$.
Lemma 1 :

We will have to work through that article to match the terms while using the Expressions for $α,β,γ$.

Thank you for proving the references and for explaining the correspondence from Gauss-Bonnet to the formula of mine! I will check the details in the provided references!

On one hand , it is somewhat easy to map the concepts , @Rowing0914 , on the other hand , it requires a lot of grunt work going over the article. Still , it will give you better Intuition & more satisfaction at the end , once you go over that.

Yeah, I just started reading the Karatas's dissertation but it seems so! My current motivation to study Theorem 10.6.4 is to extend it to quadrilaterals to discuss the possible shapes of quadrilateral Dirichlet domains.

Thank you for your support! I've posted another relevant question!
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4895788/derivation-of-a-fundamental-domains-area-formula-from-the-gauss-bonnet-theorem
